# how to display div tag under gridview row click

Tags: asp.net

I want to display selected user information in div tag which i placed under gridview, when user click on gridview selected row below that row i want to display user information.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with just a little bit of jQuery. I hope the answer below helps you

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var users = new List<object>();

    users.Add(new { Name = "Name 1", Surname = "Surname 1" });
    users.Add(new { Name = "Name 2", Surname = "Surname 2" });
    users.Add(new { Name = "Name 3", Surname = "Surname 3" });
    users.Add(new { Name = "Name 4", Surname = "Surname 4" });
    users.Add(new { Name = "Name 5", Surname = "Surname 5" });
    users.Add(new { Name = "Name 6", Surname = "Surname 6" });
    users.Add(new { Name = "Name 7", Surname = "Surname 7" });
    users.Add(new { Name = "Name 8", Surname = "Surname 8" });
    users.Add(new { Name = "Name 9", Surname = "Surname 9" });
    users.Add(new { Name = "Name 10", Surname = "Surname 10" });

    gvUsers.DataSource = users;
    gvUsers.DataBind();
}
```

**ASPX:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication6.Default2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var gridId = "<%= gvUsers.ClientID %>";
            var rowClickEvent = "#" + gridId + " tr"
            var current = "";

            $("#" + gridId).on("click", "span.close", function () {
                //Remove the row when user click on X
                $(this).parent().parent().empty();
            });

            $(rowClickEvent).click(function () {
                //Add row containing aditional info when user click on a row inside the grid view
                var row = this;
                var name = row.children[0].innerHTML;
                var surname = row.children[1].innerHTML;

                if ((name + surname) != current) {
                    $("<tr style='background-color:yellow;'><td style='height:200px;vertical-align:top;'>Dear " + name + " " + surname + "<br />Your Account Was Created Successfully<td><td style='vertical-align:top;'><span class='close'>X</span></td></tr>").insertAfter(row);
                }

                current = name + surname;
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

**Output:**

[image: Show extra info on grid row click]

Comment: coding working fine, but the problem is when i click on row below its showing div tag, again if i click on same row its showing another div tag, that i want to close div tag when i click 2nd time on gridview row

Comment: Just tweak around with the javascript a little to get it working exactly the way you want to.Please have a look at the edit to prevent duplicates from showing.You will see that I created a variable called current which you need to set to an id or another unique value(I used combination of name and surname as an example) then every time I add a row I check this variable to make sure no other div is added for that row

Comment: i found some issue with above code can you suggest me how to resolve this. For Example i clicked on Name 1 --- under row Div 1 opened if i clicked again Name 1 its not open .... thats fine..... But Issue is without close Div 1 if i click on Name 2 or 3.. --- under row Div 2 or 3... opening with out closing again i went back to Name 1 if i click again anotherr Div 1 opening bcz my old Div 1 still exist i dont want to open new Div 1 under below Name 1 row